# r increase the font size of values in dendogram plot

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram

How can I can increase the font size of labels , x2, x1, x3, x4 in the plot produced based on the function `varclus`

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(200)
x2 <- rnorm(200)
x3 <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(200)
x4 <- x2 + rnorm(200)
x <- cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4)
v <- varclus(x, similarity="spear")  # spearman is the default anyway
v    # invokes print.varclus
print(round(v$sim,2))
plot(v)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot.varclus` internally calls `plot.hclus` as you can see by running:

```
getS3method("plot",class = 'varclus')
```

and it passes along the `labels` argument (and the `...` argument(s)).
this includes a font scaling argument `cex`

so try:

```
plot(v, 
     cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: ah gotcha, I was trying cex.main, cex.sub etc. Thanks.